# Injection of banners in my webbrowsers possible malware

Tags: windows-7, browser, virus, malware

Recently I have started to suspect that I have some kind of virus on my computer. There are 3 symptoms:
Banners are being displayed on pages that doesn't use commercials, for instance when viewing screen-shots on Steam. It is only displayed after the rest of the page has been loaded and seems to be injected into it.

The whole page is replaced with a commercial with the option to skip the commercial.

The page is replaced with a search window claiming that the page could not be found.

I have tried to scan my computer with Antivir and Adaware but only found a couple of tracking cookies. I have run HijackThis but since this isn't really my area I haven't been able to discern what shouldn't be there except the line about zonealarm since I have uninstalled it.

Is there anyone out there who is able to see if there is anything suspicious in the log-file at the end or has suggestions regarding programs that might be better to find the virus than Antivir and Adaware?

Here is the whole (long) log:

```
Logfile of Trend Micro HijackThis v2.0.2  
Scan saved at 21:44:07, on 2010-04-15  
Platform: Unknown Windows (WinNT 6.01.3504)  
MSIE: Internet Explorer v8.00 (8.00.7600.16385)  
Boot mode: Normal  

Running processes:  
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\HsMgr.exe  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Personal\bin\Personal.exe  
F:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\ApacheMonitor.exe  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\avgnt.exe  
F:\Program Files (x86)\PowerISO\PWRISOVM.EXE  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\jusched.exe  
C:\Program Files\ASUS Xonar DX Audio\Customapp\ASUSAUDIOCENTER.EXE  
F:\Program Files (x86)\Voddler\service\VNetManager.exe  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Emotum\Mobile Broadband\Mobile.exe  
F:\Program Files\Logitech\SetPoint\x86\SetPoint32.exe  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Lavasoft\Ad-Aware\AAWTray.exe  
F:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe  
F:\Program Files (x86)\Trend Micro\HijackThis\HijackThis.exe  

R1 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Search Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896  
R0 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Start Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=69157  
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Page_URL = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=69157  
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Search_URL = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896  
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Search Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896  
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Start Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=69157  
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Search,SearchAssistant =   
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Search,CustomizeSearch =   
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Local Page = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\blank.htm  
R0 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar,LinksFolderName = 
F2 - REG:system.ini: UserInit=userinit.exe  
O2 - BHO: AcroIEHelperStub - {18DF081C-E8AD-4283-A596-FA578C2EBDC3} - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX\AcroIEHelperShim.dll  
O2 - BHO: gwprimawega - {83bb5261-81ec-25ae-4adf-e88936738525} - C:\Windows\SysWow64\aZfJupUw.dll  
O2 - BHO: ZoneAlarm Toolbar Registrar - {8A4A36C2-0535-4D2C-BD3D-496CB7EED6E3} - C:\Program Files\CheckPoint\ZAForceField\WOW64\TrustChecker\bin\TrustCheckerIEPlugin.dll (file missing)  
O2 - BHO: Windows Live inloggningshjälpen - {9030D464-4C02-4ABF-8ECC-5164760863C6} - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WindowsLiveLogin.dll  
O2 - BHO: Java(tm) Plug-In 2 SSV Helper - {DBC80044-A445-435b-BC74-9C25C1C588A9} - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\jp2ssv.dll  
O3 - Toolbar: ZoneAlarm Toolbar - {EE2AC4E5-B0B0-4EC6-88A9-BCA1A32AB107} - C:\Program Files\CheckPoint\ZAForceField\WOW64\TrustChecker\bin\TrustCheckerIEPlugin.dll (file missing)  
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [avgnt] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\avgnt.exe" /min  
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [PWRISOVM.EXE] f:\Program Files (x86)\PowerISO\PWRISOVM.EXE  
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [SunJavaUpdateSched] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\jusched.exe"  
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [QuickTime Task] "F:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTTask.exe" -atboottime  
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Adobe Reader Speed Launcher] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\Reader_sl.exe"  
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [VoddlerNet Manager] f:\Program Files (x86)\Voddler\service\VNetManager.exe  
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [Steam] "f:\program files (x86)\steam\steam.exe" -silent  
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [msnmsgr] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Messenger\msnmsgr.exe" /background  
O4 - Global Startup: BankID Security Application.lnk = C:\Program Files (x86)\Personal\bin\Personal.exe  
O4 - Global Startup: Logitech SetPoint.lnk = ?  
O4 - Global Startup: Monitor Apache Servers.lnk = F:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\ApacheMonitor.exe  
O13 - Gopher Prefix:   
O16 - DPF: {1E54D648-B804-468d-BC78-4AFFED8E262F} (System Requirements Lab) - http://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownload/srl/3.0.0.4/srl_bin/sysreqlab_nvd.cab  
O16 - DPF: {4871A87A-BFDD-4106-8153-FFDE2BAC2967} (DLM Control) - http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/misc/dlm-activex-2.2.5.0.cab  
O16 - DPF: {D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000} (Shockwave Flash Object) - http://fpdownload2.macromedia.com/get/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab  
O17 - HKLM\System\CCS\Services\Tcpip\..\{5F7DB2E1-29C4-4299-A483-B68B19E9F015}: NameServer = 195.54.122.221 195.54.122.211  
O17 - HKLM\System\CS1\Services\Tcpip\..\{5F7DB2E1-29C4-4299-A483-B68B19E9F015}: NameServer = 195.54.122.221 195.54.122.211  
O17 - HKLM\System\CS2\Services\Tcpip\..\{5F7DB2E1-29C4-4299-A483-B68B19E9F015}: NameServer = 195.54.122.221 195.54.122.211  
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\Alg.exe,-112 (ALG) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\alg.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: Avira AntiVir Scheduler (AntiVirSchedulerService) - Avira GmbH - C:\Program Files (x86)\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\sched.exe  
O23 - Service: Avira AntiVir Guard (AntiVirService) - Avira GmbH - C:\Program Files (x86)\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\avguard.exe  
O23 - Service: Apache2.2 - Apache Software Foundation - F:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\httpd.exe  
O23 - Service: Dragon Age: Origins - Content Updater (DAUpdaterSvc) - BioWare - F:\Program Files (x86)\Dragon Age\bin_ship\DAUpdaterSvc.Service.exe  
O23 - Service: Device Error Recovery Service (dgdersvc) - Devguru Co., Ltd. - C:\Windows\system32\dgdersvc.exe  
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\efssvc.dll,-100 (EFS) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\fxsresm.dll,-118 (Fax) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\fxssvc.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: @keyiso.dll,-100 (KeyIso) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: SAMSUNG KiesAllShare Service (KiesAllShare) - Unknown owner - F:\Program Files (x86)\Samsung\Kies\WiselinkPro\WiselinkPro.exe  
O23 - Service: Lavasoft Ad-Aware Service - Lavasoft - C:\Program Files (x86)\Lavasoft\Ad-Aware\AAWService.exe  
O23 - Service: Logitech Bluetooth Service (LBTServ) - Logitech, Inc. - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Logishrd\Bluetooth\LBTServ.exe  
O23 - Service: @comres.dll,-2797 (MSDTC) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\msdtc.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: MySQL - Unknown owner - F:\Program.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\System32\netlogon.dll,-102 (Netlogon) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: NVIDIA Display Driver Service (nvsvc) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\nvvsvc.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: Sony Ericsson OMSI download service (OMSI download service) - Unknown owner - f:\Program Files (x86)\Sony Ericsson\Sony Ericsson PC Suite\SupServ.exe  
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\psbase.dll,-300 (ProtectedStorage) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\Locator.exe,-2 (RpcLocator) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\locator.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\samsrv.dll,-1 (SamSs) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: ServiceLayer - Nokia. - C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\ServiceLayer.exe  
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\snmptrap.exe,-3 (SNMPTRAP) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\snmptrap.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\spoolsv.exe,-1 (Spooler) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\sppsvc.exe,-101 (sppsvc) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\sppsvc.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: Steam Client Service - Valve Corporation - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Steam\SteamService.exe  
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\ui0detect.exe,-101 (UI0Detect) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\UI0Detect.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\vaultsvc.dll,-1003 (VaultSvc) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: @%SystemRoot%\system32\vds.exe,-100 (vds) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\System32\vds.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: VoddlerNet - Voddler - f:\Program Files (x86)\Voddler\service\voddler.exe  
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\vssvc.exe,-102 (VSS) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\vssvc.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: @%systemroot%\system32\wbengine.exe,-104 (wbengine) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\wbengine.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: @%Systemroot%\system32\wbem\wmiapsrv.exe,-110 (wmiApSrv) - Unknown owner - C:\Windows\system32\wbem\WmiApSrv.exe (file missing)  
O23 - Service: @%PROGRAMFILES%\Windows Media Player\wmpnetwk.exe,-101 (WMPNetworkSvc) - Unknown owner - C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmpnetwk.exe (file missing)  

--  
End of file - 8958 bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
O2 - BHO: gwprimawega - {83bb5261-81ec-25ae-4adf-e88936738525} - C:\Windows\SysWow64\aZfJupUw.dll
```

This one looks very strange, while all others seem fine. Also, the name looks like just a bunch of random characters and Google can't find anything. Try to disable or delete this one.

Comment: Your answer lead my on the right path. 
I found a post on a forum written by someone with the same problem and that helped me the rest of the way.
http://www.malwareremoval.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=49694